# Extract subgroups of string

Tags: c#, regex, split

Given a string x, ex:

```
 var str = "This is the paragraph1. This is the paragraph2. This paragraph has not period";
```

I want extract only the paragraphs that end with period (.)

This is my code:

```
 var paragraphs = str.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Why the result is 3 items and not is 2 items?

The str can be variable

In this case:

```
var str = "This is the paragraph1. This is the paragraph2. This paragraph3.";
```

The result should be 3 items

Comment: I think the right syntax should be `new[] {'.'}`. Which result we are talking about exactly? Is it `paragraphs.Length`?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, the result is 3 or 2 items in the array

Comment: You must use `paragraphs.Length-1` to get the count.

Comment: Why did you add the [regex] tag? Your code doesn't use regex, and it doesn't seem to need regex. Are you looking specifically for a solution that _does_ use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to extract only the paragraph 1 and 2.

```
@"(?<=\.|^)[^.]*\."
```

**Code:**

```
String input = @"This is the paragraph1. This is the paragraph2. This paragraph has not period";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\.|^)[^.]*\.");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NsnpmI)

Answer (score 2):

> Why the result is 3 items and not is 2 items?

That's how `string.Split()` works. It *splits* the string at each point where it finds the given split text you provide. There are two such points in your string — i.e. the two periods — and so the string is split in two places.

When you split something in two places, you get three parts. So three parts are returned to you.

If you only want text that *ends* in a period, you need to use a different algorithm. One possibility is to simply *not* use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option, and ignore the last item in the returned array.